# Probability of two persons predicting cricket score correctly.

Tags: probability, solution-verification

A and B predicts the outcomes of a cricket match and their chances of predicting the runs scored by a specific batsman correctly are $\dfrac{3}{7}$ and $\dfrac{2}{5}$ respectively independent of each other. If the probability of them predicting the same wrong score is $\dfrac{1}{237}$. Given that they predicted the same score, find the probability that their answer is correct.

My approach:

$P(A^C \cap B^C) = 1 - P(A \cap B)$

$P(A \cap B) = 1 - \frac{1}{237} = \frac{236}{237}$

Is this approach and answer correct? $\frac{236}{237}$ is one of the choice answers.

Comment: No.  $\frac{236}{237}$ is the unconditional probability they do not predict the same wrong score.  But that includes the possibility they predict different scores

Comment: I think that you have a mistake in your first equation, it should be union, not intersection on the right side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some advice: When you solve problems in probability like this I strongly recommend you explicitly define your needed expressions and write down what you know and what you need to calculate. I will define $X,Y,a$ as the following:

- $X=$ the predicted number of runs by player $A$
- $Y=$ the predicted number of runs by player $B$.
- $a=$ the actual number of runs scored by the batsman.

What we know:

- $\mathbb{P}(X=a)=\frac{3}{7}$
- $\mathbb{P}(Y=a)=\frac{2}{5}$
- $X,Y$ are independent
- $\mathbb{P}(X=Y,X\neq a)=\frac{1}{237}$

We need to calculate $\mathbb{P}\left(X=a,Y=a\big|X=Y\right)$ which we can do using Bayes' rule: $$\begin{eqnarray*}\mathbb{P}(X=a,Y=a|X=Y) &=& \frac{\mathbb{P}(X=a,Y=a,X=Y)}{\mathbb{P}(X=Y)} \\ &=& \frac{\mathbb{P}(X=a,Y=a)}{\mathbb{P}(X=Y,X=a)+\mathbb{P}(X=Y,X\neq a)} \\ &=& \frac{\mathbb{P}(X=a,Y=a)}{\mathbb{P}(X=a,Y=a)+\mathbb{P}(X=Y,X\neq a)} \\ &=& \frac{\mathbb{P}(X=a)\mathbb{P}(Y=a)}{\mathbb{P}(X=a)\mathbb{P}(Y=a)+\mathbb{P}(X=Y,X\neq a)}\\ &=& \frac{\frac{3}{7}\times \frac{2}{5}}{\frac{3}{7}\times \frac{2}{5}+ \frac{1}{237}} \\ &=& \frac{1422}{1457}\end{eqnarray*}$$